# How to execute dos2unix command on multiple files in the same directory?

Tags: ansible

I tried 
- name: convert files to Unix format
   command: dos2unix “{{ scripts_dir }}/*.sh”

It says dos2unix: problems converting file. The exact same command works in shell.
I just want to know if there’s faster way around it instead of using a loop (with_items or with_fileglob).

command: dos2unix “{{ item }}”
with_fileglob: 
    - “{{ scripts_dir }}/*.sh”

The above is the current working version that I had.

Comment: Please use the formatting options, so your code is readable.

Comment: My bad. I used my phone to ask a question. Will take note of the format going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using "command" you simply execute a command. But you are using globbing (the *). This is done by a shell, i.e. bash. So you should use the shell module:

```
- name: Execute dos2unix on several files
  shell: dos2unix “{{ scripts_dir }}/*.sh"
  args:
    chdir: "/home/yourdir/"
```

Comment: Thanks! That works well. It’s so much better than using command. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain why the "home/yourdir" part? I don't get why is that for, since we have the scripts_dir folder.